# как стилизовать input таким образом?

Tags: html, css, input, scss, style

подскажите, как стилизовать инпут таким образом?[image: input]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

fieldset {
  border-radius: .5rem;
  border-color: #fcfcfc;
  padding-top: .2rem;
}

legend {
  transform: translateY(-.3rem);
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

fieldset:focus-within {
  border-color: #08f;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Комментарий</legend>
  <input type="text">
</fieldset>
```